# .NET BigInteger fractional power

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, exponentiation

Is there absolutely no way to raise a BigInteger to a double value?
Any library that does this?
Any alternative to get the same result?
Any ideas?

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.Pow( someBigInt, dblExponent );
```

Comment: Not tested as I don't have VB installed but per the documentation can do it in VB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Blam No it can't. The documentation you provide states in 'Supported Types' that everything that is not a double is converted to a double. Again, I have BigIntegers which you cannot convert to double without losing a lot a data. I'm starting to think this must be a very hard problem, no library apparently supports this. :(

Comment: You have BigInteger will all significant digits and you need to raise to a fractional power?   Many I ask the nature of the application?

Comment: When looking into this earlier I found [`this interesting related discussion`](http://www.coderanch.com/t/327637/java/java/BigInteger-math). I know it's from a Java forum, but the concepts discussed are at a lower level. It may help shed some light on the reasons why fractional power isn't readily available and if it were then it may not be accurate.